# Words generated by CFG whose parse tree contain even number of $X$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> Let $G$ be a context-free grammar with set of terminals $A$. Let $X$ be a non-terminal in $G$. Is the language of words over the alphabet $A$ with a syntax tree in which the non-terminal $X$ appears even number of times is context-free?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: You've identified this as a quote.  Any time that you copy or quote material from another source, please make sure to credit the original source.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new terminal $x$ to the alphabet, and replace $X$ with $xX$ in the right-hand side of all productions. Denote the corresponding context-free grammar by $G'$, and let $h\colon A \cup \{x\} \to A^*$ be the homomorphism erasing $x$. Then your language is $$ h(L(G') \cap A^*(xA^*xA^*)^*). $$
Since the context-free languages are xlosed under homomorphism and intersection with a regular language, it follows that your language is context-free.